# Is a continuous real-valued function with smooth level sets differentiable?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-functions

Suppose I have a function $g$ from some open subset $M \subset R^n$ to the reals. I seem to recall that if $g$ is a submersion then, for any $t$ in the range of $g$ the level set $g^{-1}(t)$ is  "smooth".

How about the converse: Suppose I only know that the function $g$ is continuous but $g^{-1}(t)$ is smooth for every $t$ in the range of $g$. Must $g$ be differentiable? Concretely, I have a smooth regular codimension one foliation $\mathscr{F}$ of $M$ and have constructed a continuous function $g$ such that, for each $t$ in the range of $g$, $g^{-1}(t)$ is a leaf of $\mathscr{F}$ ($g$ is a variant of the quotient map of $\mathscr{F}$). I've thought about this for a while now trying, among other things, using foliated charts but can't seem to get anywhere. My sense is it's true but I easily could be wrong, of course. I'd appreciate any pointers so I can work this problem out for myself.

**Edit**: Pursuant to Lee Mosher's comment, I know a few more things about the foliation $\mathscr{F}$. First, $M$ is actually $P^n$, where by $P$ I mean the strictly positive reals. Second, I know that $\mathscr{F}$ arises from a smooth plane distribution via Frobenius' Theorem (hence each leaf is a connected integral manifold which also happens to be proper). Finally, I know that every ray through the origin intersects each leaf once and only once. I still don't think that is imposing any "control" in the transverse direction, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a rock bottom counterexample take
$$g(x,y) = \begin{cases}
x & \quad\text{if $x \le 0$} \\
2x &\quad\text{if $x \ge 0$}
\end{cases}
$$
so $g^{-1}(t)$ is a vertical line for all $t$, which is as "smooth" as you can get I suppose.

But $g(x,y)$ is not differentiable at any value where $x=0$.

I'm sure you can pump this up to examples which are considerably worse behaved.

The point is that you are not imposing any control on $g$ in any direction that is "transverse" to the foliation, so its unreasonable to expect smoothness of $g$.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I believe I can see what you mean. I do have some additional "information" about the foliation (I will edit the question to add it), although I don't see right now how that will help.

Answer (score 1):

How about $g: \mathbb{R}_{>0} \to \mathbb{R}$ via:
$$
g(x) = (x-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}.
$$
Here each of your leaves are singleton which highlights the fact that the 'integrability' aspect of your assumptions aren't buying you control over the one remaining 'degree of freedom.'  The graph of $g$ is even a smooth manifold here too.

**Edit**: Your problem is actually partially related to a classical problem in economics.  You might be interested in [this](http://lib.cufe.edu.cn/upload_files/other/3_20140520040358_Smooth%20Preferences.pdf) paper by Gerard Debreu which treats a similar question, but has some nice exposition/pictures.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I am actually in the economics field and that was the first paper I looked at. It is foundational and contains a lot of the results I am getting in my research. However, I am looking to answer a slightly different question than Debreu and find that this difference may allow me to offer a more concise methodology without, unfortunately, being able to comment on the regularity of my function.

Comment: @user167131 If you're familiar with economic terminology then one way of thinking about your problem is whether *every* continuous utility whose level sets form your foliation is smooth.  Debreu shows that there exists one such utility; the crux of Lee Mosher and my examples are that you can take any such smooth solution and compose it with a non-smooth map $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ to obtain a counterexample.

Comment: I see, thanks for pointing this out. In my case the utility function is not the primary objective, but it’s very useful to see why the regularity result fails.